# Rotate the camera look (3 center's arg) around axis X in gluLookAt

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I located my camera within 3D cube -

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        ...
        glu.gluLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);
        ...
}
```

It's look like that  - (each color - side-lock ) -

[image]

Now I trying to rotate and camera looking (the three  `centerX, centerY, centerZ` ) around axis X - according to this rotation formula  -

[image]

It works well until it reach to the state which the Z's value become to negative - and after that the camera's looking start to rotate to the other side of X's axis  .

I show you the `(centerX,centerY,centerZ)` values in the range of this bug -

```
1.0 -1.2817129 0.59767246 //ok
1.0 -1.3289262 0.4836895 // ok
1.0 -1.3660256 0.36602536 //ok
1.0 -1.3927287 0.24557555 // ok
1.0 -1.4088323 0.12325676 //ok
1.0 -1.4142138 -9.784749E-8 // ok for last time
1.0 -1.4088323 -0.12325695 // rotate to other side of X
1.0 -1.3927287 -0.24557574  // so on ...
```

How you recommends for me to fix that and make it rotate on all over 360 degrees ?

**Edit:**

Does `(upX,upY,upZ)` should by rotate in this case too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rotate the direction vector about the X-axis, which is `center - eye`, not `center`. The overall computation should be `center = eye + Rot(center - eye)`.

Comment: It's the rotate operation you describe in your question.

Comment: So you mean only the `center` should be changes but as the way you describe ?

Comment: I so thank you !! it work ! :)

one more little question please   - in order to rotate around other axies (Y or Z) , does it also with `center = eye + Rot(center - eye)` (change to `Rot` in according to) ?

Comment: @URL87: Sorry, I only just noticed the above comment/question. Rot can represent whatever twisty things you want to do around the center. It can be a rotation around X multiplied by a rotation around Y, or whatever.

Comment: Since I clarified the question some more in another post and no one answered me  . you welcome - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758944/rotate-the-camera-look-around-axis-z-in-glulookat